# Flutter/Dart - Reverse Direction of Swipe Animation?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I got the following example from the Flutter.dev website. It provides a smooth `onSwipeUp` animation. But how can I modify the code to give me a smooth `onSwipeDown` animation? I tried reversing `var begin` and `var end`  but it didn't seem to do the trick and nothing happened when I swiped. Here's the swipe code;

```
onSwipeDown: (){
           Navigator.of(context).push(_opidRoute(routeaudioid: opid));
            },
```

And here's the animation;

```
    Route _opidRoute({String routeaudioid, String mastertitle}) {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: false,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => SingleOpid(opid: routeaudioid
    ),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      var begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
      var end = Offset.zero;
      var curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Any ideas how I can reverse the direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var begin = Offset(0.0, -1.0);
```